# How to display image and text in NSPopupButton's items

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage, nspopupbutton

I am working on an application and I am using NSPopupButton to have drop-down list.

I would like to know how could I display image + text in every item when I expand the list. I have seen that in the interface there is addItemWithTitle: but it takes NSString.
How could I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
[popUpButton addItemWithTitle:@"item title here"];
[[popUpButton lastItem] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"noname01"]];
```

You don't need to consider a custom view.

Answer (score 1):

The items in an NSPopUpButton are NSMenuItems which allow you to set an image for them in addition to text.

Answer (score 1):

Add the image and set the position on each menu item, like shown in the image below:

[image: Check the selected item, the position and the inspector]